# Twincat/BSD, try out on Raspberry possible?

Tags: bsd, twincat

I want to try out the new Twincat/BSD (delivery delay on Beckhoff).
Is it possible, to get the official Twincat/BSD version running on a Raspberry 4?

Edit:
I couldn't boot with the official Twincat/BSD, so i tried FreeBSD
(Version FreeBSD-14.0-CURRENT-arm64-aarch64-RPI-20210902-42c7760be3e-249088.img.xy), which workes fine.
So there are things to be done i guess, does anyone have information about that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TcBSD is possibly functional on most x86 and x64 systems, but not officially released for all beckhoff hardware (see https://www.beckhoff.com/de-de/produkte/ipc/produktfinder-ipc/ and filter for TcBSD).
ARM devices are not supported by TcBSD at the moment, so the image will not work on a raspberry.
I installed it in a virtual machine some time ago. Maybe this can be a temporary workaround for you too.